# Use Time Machine disk as regular disk without deleting all the files

Tags: time-machine

I have a disk that was a Time Machine backup for some photo files.  I now want to use that disk as a regular disk.  Can I do that without erasing the photo files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store other files on a volume that is also being used as a TM backup.

Though make sure you've got a backup for those files somewhere else. ;-)

Comment: Let me add some more information.  The disk is full of photo files, I'm a professional photographer.  I still need to work on those files, but not so often.  And there is only 85GB left on the 1TB drive.  So it seems more efficient to use it as a regular drive, backing up the those files elsewhere.

Comment: I'm confused. Is the disk full of backup copies, or source files that you're working on? You shouldn't be 'working on' backups. It doesn't seem very efficient to use the remaining 85Gb of space for 'regular' files.

Comment: So I paired the backup disk down by eliminating the older backups, but its almost full.  Hence the 85GB left.  The files on it are from shoots from 1-2yrs ago.  If I have a request to work on some I copy them to a scratch folder do the work and I'm done.    So I want to be able to easily copy and then save files to the disk.  As a TM disk it restricts some activity.  So I want to eliminate whatever is giving it the status as a TM disk and just have access to the files as I would on a regular external disk.  I just want to know how to change whatever is making the disk designated as a TM.

Comment: A volume gets the TM icon if there's a TM archive on it. You can still save files to it. However, ask yourself what do you lose if this drive stops working? The answer should be "nothing, because I have another copy". If it isn't, then you need to fix that.

Comment: What I can't do is change the folders within the drive.  Not huge, but annoying.  I get "The operation can’t be completed because backup items can’t be modified."

Comment: Your TM backups should be inside a folder at the top level of the volume, called "Backups.backupdb". If you are OUTSIDE of that top level folder, the disk should work like any other. Unless you've dragged or copied files/folders from inside the TM backup to a location outside the backup.